# Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _sdp_init_ops

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, usb, kindle, fastboot

I was trying to build a git hub source code "[imx_usb_loader](https://github.com/boundarydevices/imx_usb_loader)" using Visual Studio 2019 to fix my kindle. It is showing the following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
> _sdp_init_ops imx_uart    C:\Users\Account1\Downloads\Kindle\imx_usb_loader-master\msvc\imx_loader_config.obj 1